# Listening SSH client

Tags: ssh, remote-access

I'm looking for an SSH-equivalent (encrypted, terminal access, port forwarding) system where the client side can listen for incoming connections.

There are a number of versions of VNC where the remote end can be started as the listener and is connected to by the machine with the display that is going to be shared.

I'd like to be able to do the same thing with SSH.  Start the client end first and have it listen on a particular port, and then connect to it with the server and share the server's shell with the client.

edit:  For those who are wondering why I would be interested in such a thing:

This is going to be deployed for remote technical support of a consumer-grade network appliance. As such, obtaining login credentials for the system will likely be trivially easy for those with malicious intent. An SSH server is a very powerful application.  Yes, it can be secured in ways to prevent people from misusing access, but you can't get more secure than having the unneeded abilities not exist in the program. You don't have to worry about overlooking an exploit vector or mistyping a configuration in such a way as to leave a hole. A "listening" client would do just that. An attacker's options become severely limited when the majority of the discovered exploits against the system are going to affect *their* end only.

My attempts to search for such a thing are confounded by the commonness of the terms, hence why I am asking here. At this point I'm guessing that the easiness of setting up a reverse tunnel has resulted in little interest in such an ability, and so it does not exist. C'est la vie.

In this case, the appliance already involves connection forwarding components. If the answer is "no such thing exists" then we can piggyback it into that in a secure manner; but avoiding that chunk of work would be nice given the large number of other things that also need doing.

Final edit:

Setting up a reverse forward is probably the simplest thing to do for the average person, so I'm going to mark that as the answer.  I'm pretty sure it would be possible to use the Python Twisted framework's ssh capabilities to build a system that implements a listening client, but since the application I'll be using this to support already involves NAT traversal and port forwarding it's easier for me to use that.

If anybody stumbles across this question who wants a "backward" SSH server, feel free to leave a comment and, depending on my available time, I'll either build one, or put you in touch with someone who can build one for you.  The connection part is pretty easy, it's figuring out how to share the shell across it that's trickier than I currently have time for.

Comment: How do you get the server to connect out to the client, unless you already have some sort of connection to the server?

Comment: Sounds like what you want is ssh port forwarding.

Comment: @Sobrique  To do it with port forwarding, the remote machine must connect to the local machine and set up a forward from local to remote.  The local machine must then figure out which port is forwarded to the remote machine and connect back.  This a) requires the overhead of two ssh connections b) will make the heads of the checklist-jockeys who will be using the system explode unless I can make it 100% automated and c) gives the possibility that the user on the remote end can break out of whatever sandbox they're dumped into and do horrible things.  All things I'd like to avoid if possible.

Comment: @larsks  This is going to be used for remote support.  The connection to the server end will be via voice over telephone most likely.  Potentially via email.  Slight chance of it being via carrier-pigeon.

Comment: port forwarding works either way. You can get the remote machine to 'connect out' via ssh to a designated server, and open a backwards portforward. Check the `ssh -L` and `ssh -R` options.

Comment: @Sobrique I believe that's exactly what I said.  Remote machine connects with -R, and then local machine connects to the forwarded port.  If the remote machine can break out of the ssh sandbox they get access to the capabilities of an ssh server instead of an ssh client.  And, if I'm going to write enough code to automate that back and forth so that the average helldesk employee can handle it I might as well just write something smaller that just forwards the one port without the overhead of SSH as that would be both less resource intensive and more secure.

Comment: Doesn't have to be the same machine, nor do you need to permit interactive login. I would rather trust the security of a well known and used system, than rolling my own to do nearly the same thing, but not quite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know from your comments that isn't the solution you're looking for.

But I will reiterate my opinion. Use ssh port forwarding. It really is the tool for this job.

Here's how you would do it:

- Configure yourself a DMZ 'ssh endpoint' host. For bonus points, make several that are VMs.
- Firewall your DMZ ssh endpoint, such that NO outbound traffic is permitted from the box.
- firewall your endpoint to restrict 'incoming' connections to *only* specific ports from the 'outside world' and a slightly less limited list from your 'trusted' network.
- configure chroot
- set up an account with that chroot.
- Put into your chroot a script that says 'ssh session connected' or similar.
- Create a script on the box, that your *support* users can run (either script or web interface), to 'enable' an incoming support session.
- Your 'create support session' script: creates a new username, generates an ssh public-private key pair, and assigns a port number (prints this for your support guy).
- authorized_keys allows you to specify 'permitted' commands.
- If you really want, you can use iptables on the host and explicitly enable incoming from specific remote IP addresses. (If you know what they are!)
- It then puts the 'run ssh' command, including bundled temp ssh public key into a packet that can be fetched via web browser then executed by the remote customer 'wget | sh' or just 'click this link and run it'.
- Your support guy then sshes into your server, and does his own port forward - forwarding his local ports, so he can point his client (VNC etc.) at a fixed location (localhost:port)
- once your support session is done, your support guy runs another script (via a menu if they can't cope with a command line) to delete the account and blow away the chroot environment. (close firewall rule if relevant)

Your risk of compromise is low, because this is a DMZ host with no interactive login and no outbound connection. (You may want to allow it access for patch fetching, but whatever).

It proxies two sessions, but requires *both* ends to 'connect in' meaning there's just nothing there to 'hack' when a session isn't active.

And because you're using a well known server/client/protocol, you get all the support and maintenance that open source offers. Which is almost certainly a lot more than you'll get for hand rolled code to do almost the same thing.

You're no longer relying on a 'code solution' to your problem, but a technical infrastructure one. You also have firewalls that can inspect incoming/outgoing traffic quite easily, making intrusion detection trivially easy.

Comment: Thanks for the writeup. Since listening SSH doesn't seem to be a thing like listening VNC is I'll probably mark it as the best answer eventually.  For our purposes we'll probably piggyback it into the connection relaying that we're already doing for other parts of the application; I was just hoping for an even simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this with ssh port forwarding, set up by having your client initiate an outbound connection from their server to some endpoint that you set up.  This is actually a fairly common mechanism (I've dealt with at least major storage vendors who have handled remote connectivity this way in the past).

Have your client run something like:

```
ssh -R 2200:localhost:22 support@your.endpoints.address
```

They will obviously need to authenticate at this point, using either a password or ssh key that you have provided to them.

Once connected, if you are on the system at `your.endpoint.address`, you can run:

```
ssh -p 2200 user@localhost
```

To connect as user `user` to the system from which the client initiated their connection.  This will of course require that you have some login credentials for that side of things.

Comment: If I do it this way, the security of the your.endpoints.address ssh server will have to be absolutely flawless or else It'll end up being used (at the very least) to relay traffic for crackers and pedophiles.  It's suitable for low-volume support where the server can be monitored closely and its address won't be widely known. Given the scope of what I'm working on, I'd rather have a system that gives less (potential) power to the support client.  I'll write it myself if I have to, but I'd rather not recreate the wheel.

Comment: The security of your endpoint doesn't have to be any more or less secure than any other public-facing service.  I'm not sure how you envision it being used "by pedophiles", but I think you've raised the crazy of this question to a level that I'm no longer comfortable helping out.  Good luck.

Comment: My apologies for the choice of terminology. Let me put it this way:  The system I am looking to build, in order to function as I need it to, must necessarily have access credentials distributed to potentially hundreds of thousands of locations. Which means that anybody who wants to log into the SSH server on my end *will* be able to get their hands on the ability to do so. A big part of securing an SSH server is making sure that unauthorized users cannot log in, and that goes out the window with this support model. I will edit my question to explain why I am interested in such a thing.